# PostgreSQL server is not connecting after Service Restart

Tags: postgresql

I have edited my pg_hba file(Added a row at the end host all ..... Xxxxxx/32"  and copied it to server and restarted the services by "sudo service postgresql restart" but after that the server is not connecting.

Showing the below error,
   Your database returned: 
   "Connection to 
    138.2xx.1xx.xx:5432 refused. 
    Check that the hostname and port 
    are correct and that the 
    postmaster is accepting TCP/IP 
    connections."

The Jenkins job and data visualization tools are failing which was working fine previously. What could be the reason.

Getting this in PostgreSQL Log

```
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11761] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11761] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11766] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2019-10-23 07:21:25.832 CEST [11763] LOG:  shutting down
2019-10-23 07:21:25.919 CEST [11761] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-10-23 07:21:27.068 CEST [22633] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-23 07:21:25 CEST
2019-10-23 07:21:27.073 CEST [22633] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-10-23 07:21:27.075 CEST [22631] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-10-23 07:21:27.075 CEST [22637] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-10-23 07:21:27.390 CEST [22639] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: Look the PostgreSQL server log file to see what the problem is.

Comment: @jjanes any other thing/ solutions.The postgreSQL log is located at var/log/postgresql/postgreSQL 11/ this folder right?  Also is there anything to be checked?

Comment: Different installers put the logs in different places, but that does seem like a likely one.  Does it report that the server failed to start due to errors in pg_hba.conf?  Does it say that "database system is ready to accept connections"?

Comment: @jjanes Edited the answer and updated the log entries.

Comment: can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Do you get one "incomplete startup packet" for every connection attempt?  Or was it just that one message immediately after start up?